# Why is my excel reader class reading every field correctly except for the date field?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, interop

I am reading in multiple fields from an excel sheet using Interop and it is working almost perfectly. Every field is read in except for the date field, which is populated by a weird number that has nothing to do with anything on the excel document. My code that is needed to run the program is below. In order to see the problem the test class must be run in order to see the results that are printed out on the console as well as the tests in the test class. The excel file must be on the desktop and titled TEST.xlsx. If you need to check my Excel sheet it is linked [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1afZfA6v94RH46OppX3rNTo_z5w25rO4IrP6KLKSky1M/edit?usp=sharing) on a google document.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using _Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class reads data from an excel sheet and stores the data in Sales objects
    /// and then places each Sale into a List of Sales. 
    /// </summary>
    public class Reader
    {
        public string path;
        public _Application excel;
        public _Workbook wb;
        public _Worksheet ws;
        public List<Sales> salesList { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// This constructor opens the excel file, creates a list of sales, creates a modifier
        /// object. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="path"> Name of the excel file to be opened.  </param>
        /// <param name="sheet"> Sheet number within the excel file. </param>
        public Reader(string path, int sheet)
        {

            this.path = path;

            excel = new _Excel.Application();
            wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
            ws = wb.Worksheets[sheet];

            salesList = new List<Sales>();
            createSales();

            // Console output test to ensure the excel file is being read correctly. 
            for (int i = 0; i < salesList.Count; i++ )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Row: " + (i + 1).ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(salesList[i].salesNum);
                Console.WriteLine(salesList[i].material);
                Console.WriteLine(salesList[i].description);
                Console.WriteLine(salesList[i].MSPS);
                Console.WriteLine(salesList[i].MRPC);
                Console.WriteLine(salesList[i].quantity);
                Console.WriteLine(salesList[i].date);
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }

        public Reader()
        {
            new Reader("", 1);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method creates a new Sale for every row in the excel file. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns> Number of rows (sales) in the excel sheet. </returns>
        public int createSales()
        {
            int rows = 1; // Excel sheets start at 1 not 0. 

            while (ws.Cells[rows, 1].Value2 != null)
            {
                Sales sale = new Sales();
                addFields(sale, rows);
                salesList.Add(sale);

                rows++;
            }

            return rows;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This helper method adds fields to all of the sales.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sale"> Sale that is getting fields filled. </param>
        /// <param name="row"> Row to look for fields on </param>
        private void addFields(Sales sale, int row)
        {
            int i = 1;

            sale.salesNum = readCell(row, i);              // Sales Number field
            i++;

            sale.material = readCell(row, i);              // material field
            i++;

            sale.description = readCell(row, i);           // Description field
            i++;

            sale.MSPS = readCell(row, i);                  // MSPS field
            i++;

            sale.MRPC = readCell(row, i);                  // MRPC field
            i++;

            sale.quantity = readCell(row, i);              // Quantity field
            i++;

            sale.date = readCell(row, i);                  // Date field            
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method reads a cell from the excel document. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="i"> The x-coordinate of the cell to read. </param>
        /// <param name="j"> The y-coordinate of the cell to read. </param>
        /// <returns> Data in the cell in a string. </returns>
        private string readCell(int i, int j)
        {
            if (ws.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
            {
                return ws.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }
        }

    }
}

using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ConsoleApplication1;

namespace AutomationProgramTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class ReaderTest
    {

        Reader reader; 


        [TestMethod]
        public void testCreateSales()
        {
            reader = new Reader(@"C:\Users\abochel\Desktop\TEST.xlsx", 1);

            // Check if the list added every sale. 
            Assert.AreEqual(90, reader.salesList.Count);

            // Check contents of sales[0].
            Assert.AreEqual("5/11/2017", reader.salesList[0].date);

            // Check contents of sales[1]
            Assert.AreEqual("5/11/2017", reader.salesList[1].date);

            // Check contents of sales[89]
            Assert.AreEqual("5/22/2017", reader.salesList[0].date);
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using _Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Created and tested by Alexander James Bochel. 
    /// Last Updated: 6/7/2017
    /// </summary>
    class Program
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// This will call the rest of the classes in the program. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args"> Command line arguments. </param>
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            openAndExecute(); 
        }




        public static void openAndExecute()
        {
            Reader reader = new Reader(@"C:\Users\abochel\Desktop\TEST.xlsx", 1);
        }

    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class contains information about each individual row on the excel sheet. 
    /// </summary>
    public class Sales
    {
        // Each variable is a cell in the row for each sales order in excel. 
        public String salesNum { get; set; }
        public String material { get; set; }
        public String description { get; set; }
        public String MSPS { get; set; }
        public String MRPC { get; set; }
        public String quantity { get; set; }
        public String date { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Basic Constructor. 
        /// </summary>
        public Sales()
        {
            // TODO finish basic constructor. 
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This constructor sets up all of the variables within each sale. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="salesN"> Sales number </param>
        /// <param name="mat"> Type of material </param>
        /// <param name="desc"> Description </param>
        /// <param name="MS"> IDK </param>
        /// <param name="MR"> IDK </param>
        /// <param name="quant"> How many </param>
        /// <param name="dat"> IDK </param>
        public Sales(String salesN, String mat, String desc, String MS, String MR, String quant,
                     String dat)
        {
            // Can these be deleted. 
            salesNum = salesN;
            material = mat;
            description = desc;
            MSPS = MS;
            MRPC = MR;
            quantity = quant;
            date = dat;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That weird number is actually just a representation of the date in a different format. You can try using the `CDate()` function on that number and that should give you the date you are looking for. Another option would be to set it to a variable that is explicitly defined as a date type.